# Is there any other way to load sprites?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

Hi there I was wondering if in unity there is any other way of loading sprites during game, that doesn't include using resources.load. That's because i have some large images and load seemse to be quite consuming.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream classes can be used to control loading process instead of Resources.Load(). In this way, you can partially load a resource, stop loading, and resume the loading later. Below link will be helpful.

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/160787-Texture-Stream-Loading